# Creating list of intersected polygons for each line using QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, overlapping-features, virtual-layer, concatenation

I have a line layer representing transport routes.

I would like to add a Virtual Layer listing every city crossed by each line. I would only need the id of each city to be listed (column `"Code_INSEE"`).

The result should be:

```
Line 1 | 12001, 12003, 12122               |
Line 2 | 23001, 23002, 23004, 23120, 23012 |
etc.
```

[image]

This question is linked to the solution proposed in this topic: [Automatic calculation field based on line modification within QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/309138/20802)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One sample ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` (using Natural Earth admin dataset):

```sql
SELECT x.name AS LineName,
       Group_Concat(x.admin, ',') AS CountryNames
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM Line 
  CROSS JOIN Countries ON st_intersects(Line.geometry, Countries.geometry)
) as x
GROUP BY x.name
```

[image]

For your case it will probably be:

```sql
SELECT x.name AS LineName,
       Group_Concat(x.Code_INSEE, ',') AS CityNames
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM lines 
  CROSS JOIN cities ON st_intersects(lines.geometry, cities.geometry)
) as x
GROUP BY x.name
```

(Assuming your Line layer name is `lines` and the City polygon layer is `cities`, and the Line number is stored in `name` field).

Comment: Perfect ! This is exactly what i needed ! Kudos to you