# Summing flow from cities listed in another layer within QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I have transport flow represented by arrows within QGIS in one layer. The database is coded with cities ID for the origin and cities ID for the destination of the flow.

[image: Flow]

I also have in another layer, transporte lines with id of cities crossed by this line (using [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/309359/20802) to [Creating list of intersected polygons for each line using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309344))

[image: Line description]

I would like to get the sum of flow between cities crossed by my transport lines

> Line 1 : sum of 'flow' case when 'ORIGIN' is like 'CITIES_INTERSECTED'
> AND when 'DESTINATION' is like 'CITIES_INTERSECTED'
>
> Line 2: sum of
> 'flow' case when 'ORIGIN' is like 'CITIES_INTERSECTED' AND when
> 'DESTINATION' is like 'CITIES_INTERSECTED'

Something like this i suppose

Comment: What if you use attribute name "flow" in the SELECT query you used according to https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/309359/20802 ? Or you can write a PyQGIS script (a nested for loop), and iterate through the ids of the lines and sum the flow values.

Comment: I am totally fine with the usage of another virtual layer and the query. But I find it difficult to get how to refer to a field already calculated but a virtual layer? My cities intersected field is in a cirtual layer indeed